# Where to see the cost of my last Skype call

Tags: linux, skype

I use my personal Skype account to call work partners, and need a trace of the cost (a screenshot would be enough) of my last call, that I can paste on my expenses sheet.

Question: Where can the cost of a Skype call be seen?

Ideally it would show something like this:

```
Wednesday 4th October 2017, +336864864, 84 minutes, 7.32 EUR
```

Substracting the balance after-before is not a solution, because it can not be pasted easily on an expenses sheet.

I use Skype for Linux 5.5.0.1 but I can check other platforms if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get monthly statements as you would for your Bank Account.

[What are monthly statements and how do i get them](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34517/what-are-monthly-statements-and-how-do-i-get-them?platform=linux)

> Monthly statements are available to download from MyAccount. These statements contain a summary of Skype Credit and subscriptions purchased, details of how you used your Skype credit (e.g. to make calls, send SMS, or use Wi-Fi), and any other adjustments including refunds to your account.

I am not sure if this will show you the latest calls though. There is also the Skype Manager page where you can see reports of the usage

[Can I monitor a member's usage with Skype Manager™?](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA561/can-i-monitor-a-member-s-usage-with-skype-manager?platform=linux)

> The report provides details for each time the member used Skype Credit, including when it was used, what it was used for, the rate per minute of the call, the call duration and the cost.

And here is where you can see your usage:

https://secure.skype.com/account/usage

Comment: The first page you link to states "Click Purchase history at the bottom of the page" but there is no such link.

Comment: https://secure.skype.com/account/usage is exactly what I needed, thanks :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul well there are some changes since this documentation. But you can find the purchase history in https://secure.skype.com/portal/overview. under billing and payments. That is for the monthly statements. But since you are doing your own expense sheet I'm glad the usage tab works for you